# Recover Jobs from a MSDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to recover the jobs from a MSDB file. I had to fully reinstall a new SQL Server and Windows Server, but apparently I forgot to ever do a MSDB backup. Yup, big blunder. Now I need to restore it or at least get the jobs out of it, which are essential to day-to-day operations. Our tape backups that have the backup I need will arrive here by Saturday but I don't want to risk another day without those jobs running. I tried to the sp_dbattach procedure so I could get the scripts out but apparently the log file is broken because it had some transactions going on when the other server went down. Do I have any option?

Comment: You have the files from an instance that crashed, and you're trying to attach the msdb from the crashed instance to a new instance?

Comment: Exactly. I have both MDF and LDF of the MSDB

Comment: you might be able to use `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH` syntax to attach the `.mdf`.  Be sure to use some other name, such as `msdb_old` for the database name.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to connect the `msdb.mdf` using:

```
CREATE DATABASE msdbtest ON (
    NAME = 'msdb_data'
    , FILENAME = 'c:\path_to_your_old_msdb\msdb_data.mdf'
) FOR ATTACH;
```

Note, depending on the operating system where you are running the above command, you may need to elevate permissions for SQL Server Management Studio (runas administrator) for the command to work.  See my question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53756/access-denied-error-in-create-database-for-attach) for details.

I purposely corrupted the .ldf on my machine before attaching the file, and received the following error message about the newly attached `msdbtest` database:

```
File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\SQLServer\Logs\msdbtest_log.ldf" may be incorrect.
New log file 'c:\sqlserver\data\msdbtest_log.ldf' was created.
Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum 
(expected: 0xa3ba6e3e; actual: 0x208d1401). It occurred during a read of page (2:0)
 in database ID 11 at offset 0000000000000000 in file 'C:\SQLServer
 \Logs\msdbtest_log.ldf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system
 event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens 
 database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database 
 consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more 
 information, see SQL Server Books Online.
```

I ran `DBCC CHECKDB('msdbtest')` which reported no errors.  I was then able to run the following `SELECT` statements to see details about the jobs stored in msdb.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobs
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobsteps
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobstepslogs
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobschedules
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobservers
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobhistory
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobactivity
```

You could use the information stored in these tables to recreate the jobs.

Comment: I tried this but it gave me a similar error from the 4th line onwards. I corrupted the MDF with a Hex file but no go.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to corrupt the file on purpose.  I did that to try to mimic your environment.

Comment: @MaxVernon would you go as far as calling that a bad idea?

Comment: @Zane - yah - bad idea!

Comment: @LordRelix did you try it without corrupting the mdf first?